# Can Ezreal's Q trigger multiple times with Iceborn Gauntlet?

Tags: league-of-legends

Ezreal's Q is as follows:

> Ezreal fires a bolt of energy in a line that will deal physical damage and apply on-hit effects to the first enemy it hits. **If it
>   strikes an enemy unit, all of Ezreal's cooldowns will be reduced by 1
>   second.**

If I hit multiple enemies due to the iceborn gauntlet, will it deduct 1 second of cooldown for every minion hit?

Comment: I'd say no because the language is "If it strikes an enemy unit" and not "For each enemy unit hit"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's not how the logic works.

Instead, it behaves like this:

```
  Did Q hit *any* enemy?
  -- Yes -> Reduce Cooldown by 1
  -- No  -> break;
```

For this same reason, a Nasus who kills multiple minions with his Q (due to Tiamat or Frostborn Gauntlet (or both!) ) will only power up Siphoning Strike by one minion's worth of damage.

Comment: Are you sure for Nasus ? I'm prettry sure that when the gauntlet came out I tested to last hit 2 minions and it gave me 2xBonus of the Q

Comment: @Hystic I think it likely you killed large minion (which now give double bonus). I have tested this myself, and last I knew, only the minion that takes damage from the siphoning strike itself (as opposed to dying from gauntlet or tiamat damage) garners the benefit.

Comment: @MarcoLeblanc Actually, you're incorrect, I've tested it multiple times since the changes on Nasus and only 1 critter is counted, I did an AD test build (so that I could easily kill waves with tiamats/IBG) and was only getting an increase from the critter I directly hit.

Comment: Hmm I guess you're right.  Works for Parrrrley, though :) +1 if theres an edit to the answer

Answer (score 1):

No, because Mystic Shot's tooltip reads like this:

> **Mystic Shot - Active:** Ezreal fires a bolt of energy in a line that will deal physical damage and apply on-hit effects to the first enemy
>   it hits. ***If it strikes an enemy unit, all of Ezreal's cooldowns will
>   be reduced by 1 second.***

You hit an enemy, so it gets reduced by a second.  If it was cumulative, it would say something like "cooldowns are reduced by 1 second for each target hit" or something similar.